# Problem in adding tags with taggit in Django

Tags: django, django-taggit

```
class Events(models.Model):
    user_name = models.TextField()
    e_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.e_name

    def create_event(self, value):
        self.user_name = value['username']
        self.e_url = value['url']
        self.tags = value['tags']
```

Tags are not storing. When i store them from admin view its working properly. Bur when i try from my webpage its not working.

Here value['tags'] contain string with comma separated tag name e.g. 'python,cpp,django'.

My tags table is storing nothing in this case

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

Comment: Are you using `django-taggit` ?

Comment: yes, all the modules is successfully imported